# Choose out of multivariate normal pdf

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, particle-filter

I have some questions about `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`.

1. What does it return? I understand that when using:

   ```
   var = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(mean, cov)
   z = var.pdf([x,y])
   ```

   I'll get in z the pdf of this index. Is this true?
2. I assumed that the mean given is the peak of the pdf. Am I right?
3. I want to create a 4D map of gaussian pdf, and choose out of it randomly, by the pdf, `N` points (for particle filter predicting). To use `np.choose` I need to create an array of the pdf values of shape `(M,1)`, and an array of the 4D points of shape `(M, 4)`.

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal distribution is quite ubiquitous and implemented in many different places, so I think you would be better off using the random normal sampling from numpy: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html. In this function you can specify the shape of the output.

Answer (score 0):

using DIN's answer, that's what I did:

```
x_predict = np.random.normal(mean[0], covs[0], N)
y_predict = np.random.normal(mean[1], covs[1], N)
sx_predict = np.random.normal(mean[2], covs[2], N)
sy_predict = np.random.normal(mean[3], covs[3], N)
particles = np.dstack((x_predict, y_predict, sx_predict, sy_predict))
```